# XNA 4.0 для Windows Phone 7 (шейдера)

Tags: xna, xna-4, 2d, windows-phone-7, разработка-игр

**Собственно вопрос.**

Существует ли возможность использовать шейдера в XNA 4.0 для WP7 ?

И если нет то, как сделать освещение для 2D ?

Answer (score 1):

В xna 4.0 нет, надо юзать движок, например sunburn.